# Why the IndexedDB cursor.value.key from a dictionary key gives me undefined?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to append each value from each key from the dictionary that was added in the IDB to a cell on a table.

The way that the dictionary was added goes something like this:

```
var trans_write = data_base.transaction(["students"], "readwrite");
var petition_write = trans_write.objectStore("students");
var query = petition_write.add(dictionary);
```

> data_base is the global variable that stored the `e.target.result;` when the onsuccess event was triggered

Then I passed the same dictionary to a function that will iterate the value from each key from the same dictionary so I can add its value to a cell, then the cell to a row and finally to the main table:

```
function displayDataOnTable(dictionary) {

    var trans = data_base.transaction(["students"], "readonly");
    var query = trans.objectStore("students");

    var cursor = query.openCursor();
    cursor.addEventListener("success", function(e) {

        var the_cursor = e.target.result;

        if (the_cursor) {

            var new_row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var key in dictionary) {

                var cell_data = the_cursor.value.key;
                var new_cell = document.createElement("td");
                new_cell.append(cell_data);
                new_row.append(new_cell);

            }

            table.append(new_row);
            the_cursor.continue();

        }

    }, false);

}
```

> As you can guess, table is the global variable that has assigned a HTMLTable who was obtain by its id: `document.getElementById("idTable");`

The issue that I'm having is that the line `var cell_data = the_cursor.value.key;` assigns `cell_data` as `undefined` and also the iterator `key` from `for (var key in dictionary)` quotes that it is declared but it is never readed. So that results in the table having in all its cells "undefined".

Any solutions? Best regards. Thanks.

Update #2 (Sharing the original full code, both JS and HTML. English is not my primary language, so excuse me for that):

```
var campos = [];
var base_de_datos;
var tabla;

function main() {

    var ids_campo = [
        "no_control", "nombre", "curp", "masculino", 
        "femenino", "otro", "grado", "grupo", 
        "peso", "estatura", "sangre", "fecha_nac"
    ];
    var boton_reg = document.getElementById("envio_datos");
    var abrir_bd = indexedDB.open("AlumnosBD");
    tabla = document.getElementById("tablaDatosAlumno");

    abrir_bd.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {

        base_de_datos = e.target.result;
        base_de_datos.createObjectStore("alumnos", {keyPath: "no_control"});

    }

    abrir_bd.onsuccess = function(e) {

        base_de_datos = e.target.result;

    }

    boton_reg.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        obtenerCampos(ids_campo);
        agregarDatosAlObjetoStore();

    }, false);

}

function obtenerCampos(ids_campo) {

    for (i = 0; i < ids_campo.length; i++) {

        if (i >= 3 && i <= 5) {

            var radio_button = document.getElementById(ids_campo[i]);
            if (radio_button.checked) {

                campos.push(radio_button);

            }

        } else {

            campos.push(document.getElementById(ids_campo[i]));

        }

    }  

}

function agregarDatosAlObjetoStore() {

    var valores = [];
    var dicc = {};//haciendo diccionario con las claves y valores para luego añadirlo a la bd.

    for (i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {

        if (i == 3){ 

            valores.push(campos[i].id);
            dicc[campos[i].name] = valores[i];

        } 

        valores.push(campos[i].value);
        dicc[campos[i].id] = valores[i];

    }

    var trans_write = base_de_datos.transaction(["alumnos"], "readwrite");
    var peticion_escritura = trans_write.objectStore("alumnos");
    var query = peticion_escritura.add(dicc);

    query.addEventListener("success", function() {

        alert("Datos añadidos satisfactoriamente.")
        mostrarDatosEnTabla(dicc);

    }, false)

}

function mostrarDatosEnTabla(d) {

    var trans_lectura = base_de_datos.transaction(["alumnos"], "readonly");
    var peticion_lectura = trans_lectura.objectStore("alumnos");

    var puntero = peticion_lectura.openCursor();
    puntero.addEventListener("success", function(e) {

        var indice_puntero = e.target.result;

        if (indice_puntero) {

            var fila_nueva = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var clave in d) {

                var info_celda = indice_puntero.value.clave
                var celda_nueva = document.createElement("td");
                celda_nueva.append(info_celda);
                fila_nueva.append(celda_nueva);

            }

            tabla.append(fila_nueva);
            indice_puntero.continue();

        }

    }, false);

}

window.addEventListener("load", main, false);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
    <head>
        <title>HTML</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name = "keywords" content = "Test">

        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styleForm.css">
       <script src = "scriptDB.js"></script> 

    </head>

    <body>

        <section id = "zonaFormulario">

            <datalist id = "tipos_sangre">
                <option value = "A+"></option>
                <option value = "A-"></option>
                <option value = "B+"></option>
                <option value = "B-"></option>
                <option value = "O+"></option>
                <option value = "O-"></option>
                <option value = "AB+"></option>
                <option value = "AB-"></option>
            </datalist>

            <form id = "reg_alumno" method = "get">

                

                <div id = "seccion1">

                    <p id = "lbl_secc1">CURP:    &nbsp;<input id = "curp"  name = "curp"  minlength = "18" maxlength = "18" required></p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc1">NOMBRE:  &nbsp;<input id = "nombre" name = "nombre" type = "text" maxlength = "60" required></p>
                    

                </div>

                <div id = "seccion2">

                    <p id = "lbl_secc2">Género:</p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc2"><input type = "radio" id = "masculino" name = "genero" required> Masculino</p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc2"><input type = "radio" id = "femenino" name = "genero" required> Femenino</p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc2"><input type = "radio" id = "otro" name = "genero" required> Otro</p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc2">No. de Control: &nbsp;<input id = "no_control" name = "no_control" type = "text" pattern = "[0-9]{8}" maxlength = "8" required></p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc2">Grado: &nbsp;<input id = "grado" name = "grado" type = "number" min = "1" max = "9" required></p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc2">Grupo: &nbsp;<input id = "grupo" name = "grupo" type = "text" pattern = "[A-D]" required></p>

                </div>

                <div id = "seccion3">

                    <p id = "lbl_secc3">Peso:                  &nbsp;<input id = "peso" name = "peso" type = "number" min = "32" max = "150" required></p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc3">Estatura:              &nbsp;<input id = "estatura" name = "estatura" type = "number" min = "120" max = "200" required></p>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc3">Tipo de sangre:        &nbsp;<input id = "sangre" name = "sangre" type = "text"  list = "tipos_sangre" required></p>
                    <br><br>
                    <p id = "lbl_secc3">Fecha de nacimiento:   &nbsp;<input id = "fecha_nac" name = "fecha_nac" type = "date" required></p>

                </div>

                <div id = "seccion4">

                    <input type="button" id = "envio_datos" name = "envio_datos" value = "Registrar">

                </div>

            </form>

        </section>

        <section id = "zonaTabla">

            <table id = "tablaDatosAlumno">

                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Número de control</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>CURP</th>
                        <th>Género</th>
                        <th>Grado</th>
                        <th>Grupo</th>
                        <th>Peso (kg)</th>
                        <th>Estatura (cm)</th>
                        <th>Tipo de sangre</th>
                        <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
    
                    </tr>

                </thead>

            </table>

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read data from IndexedDB until after it has been written to IndexedDB. You are most likely calling `displayDataOnTable` before the data has been written. If you query for data before it exists, then you will experience the problems you are describing.

For more help, please provide the code that calls the write code, and show when you call the write code, where in your code you wait for the write call to complete, and then where in the code you perform the read.

Remember, IndexedDB's API uses non-blocking functions. If you start performing a write, do not wait for it to complete (block until it is complete), and then start a read, you have a race condition. Search through the questions with the keywords "indexeddb" and "async" to learn more, or search around for general topics on asynchronous JavaScript.

Comment: Just updated the post with the full code. The data its being added before it is readed. I'm sure of it because I can visualize it from the Application >> Storage section from the Chrome web inspector once I click the button that appends it. The issue starts when I want to retrive that info from the DB